# Where are the windows firewall logs stored?

Tags: windows, windows-7, firewall, log-files

I don't know where Windows 7 stores the logs for the windows firewall. Can anybody tell me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log